# How to resume download of ipad firmware update

Tags: windows, itunes, download, ipad, software-update

I have an iPad 2, and I would like to update to iOS 6. But every time I pause the download in iTunes, the download gets reset to zero kB. I don't have a stable internet connection, so it's impossible for me to get that download in one go. Why does iTunes keep cancelling the download instead of actually pausing it, and what can I do to upgrade iOS on this iPad. I'm running iTunes on Windows XP but the same failures are occurring on 7 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an iPad that is running iOS 4, then you can manually update your iPad from this link.

http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/02/download-ipad-firmware-ipsw/

Scroll down to iOS 6 and pick the corresponding iPad. Also, the difference between an iPad Wifi  and a iPad(2,4) is that iPad(2,4) should have come preloaded with iOS 5.1. So in this case you want iPad 2 Wifi.

The direct link for iPad 2 Wifi is below:

http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS6/Restore/041-0804.20120919.9SgHU/iPad2,1_6.0_10A403_Restore.ipsw

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

That's some pretty bad luck. There is no way to continue a download from where you left off. Apple doesn't want the download to get corrupted, so they redownload every time. You could try going to Settings-->General-->Software Update on your iPad, and download the update from there. I'm not sure if it will help though. Otherwise, I would suggest going somewhere with Wifi (Mcdonalds or something) and doing what I said above on your iPad itself.

Get something to eat though, it could take a while.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's on iOS 4 currently, which doesn't provide the option to update directly from the iPad.

Comment: Well, do you have a laptop with iTunes? You could do the same thing with the laptop if you go somewhere with stable internet.

Comment: Actually, I found this site with links to the [actual files](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/19/ios-6-ipsw-direct-download-links/) that iTunes downloads from, but I don't know which one to get now. iPad 2 2,4 or iPad 2 wifi (mine is wifi only).

Comment: the iPad model is MC769ZP, if you could tell me which ipsw on [that link](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS6/Restore/041-0804.20120919.9SgHU/iPad2,1_6.0_10A403_Restore.ipsw), I'd appreciate it.

Comment: iPad 2 wifi is the correct one.

Comment: Actually, give me a minute. Maybe it's not.

Comment: Okay, yes iPad 2 wifi is the correct download link. I'll post another answer so that it's easier to read.